# Establish weights in a list on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was wondering if any one could help me.  I have a list of elements (journals names). However, some of them can be classified in different 'categories'.

What I did is the following:

I create the id list with increment numbers when value changes in another column. I've used the following formula, and the result is in the second column, as it can be seen in screen shot.

```
`=IF(D2<>D1;1;E1+1`
```

So, what I wanted to do, is to assign weights to each of the categories. For instance, if an element (in this example), a journal is classified into three categories, assign a `0.3` of weight to each of the elements that composed that journal; if it is `4`, `0.25` (the maximum I observed is 6).

How can I do this? Any suggestions would be very valuable!

**EDIT:** By the way, the result I will obtain is the following (third column)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laqZb.png)

Comment: This issue is bit confusing could you please [edit] the post and add expected result, will help us to fix it.

Comment: What if say for example AATCC REVIEW again exists somewhere else in bottom rows? Are you going to start again with 1 for it? Or is it ensured that all same entries always remain in contiguous cells?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thanks, i have edited the post. Hope it's clearer!! Patkim, there are no duplicates on the bottom rows (I also checked it). The second column with the id works perfectly. I also make sure about this (they always remain in contiguous cells).

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelleCrayon,, now check my post I've solved it ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example here. Suppose your list is in D3:D14 put the following formula in E3 and drag it down.

```
=1/(COUNTIF($D$3:$D$14,D3))
```

Depending upon your regional settings, you may have to replace comma (,) with a semi-colon (;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot patkim!!! :) It worked!

Answer (score 0):

*The worksheet function `COUNTIF` wrapped with `IF` can solve the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell `AF1`:

  `=COUNTIF($AE$1:$AE1,$AE1)`
- Formula in cell `AG1`:

  ```
  =IF(COUNTIF($AE$1:$AE$19,$AE1)=1,1,IF(COUNTIF($AE$1:$AE$19,$AE1)=2,0.5,IF(COUNTIF($AE$1:$AE$19,$AE1)=3,0.3,"")))
  ```

**N.B.**

- *For new categories, you may extend the formula if & when required.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*